# Check for a specific taxonomy of a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a books custom post type, I want to do something only on the 'book_categories' pages and other stuff on the 'book_year' pages.

How do I check if I'm on those taxonomy pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`is_tax()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/):

```
if ( is_tax( 'book_categories' ) ) {

}

if ( is_tax( 'book_year' ) ) {

}
```